# Django: Create DatabaseWrapper for dynamic database connection

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

sorry for my english.

I want to create a DatabaseWrapper because I want to make a dynamic database connection. 
I need an object of the DatabaseWrapper for the Django Querybuilder: http://django-query-builder.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/query.html#querybuilder.query.Query

Why?
- Because I don't want to store the database config in the settings.py - DATABASE variable.
I want to create a connection during the runtime and close it after my class is used. The reason for that is that if I want to test, Django creates a test_database on the second database. Surely this is not a problem but I don't have writing privileges on the database, hence my tests fail every time.

Comment: Why do you need to run your tests in an environment where you don't have write access to your database? What's the point?

Comment: I have multiple databases. One is my environment and the other database is used for importing things in my database. So I just want to get a connection to this database with my QueryBuilder. Does this answer helps you?

Comment: I would see what this method expects to receive for a "connection": http://django-query-builder.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/query.html#querybuilder.query.Query.__init__

Comment: The documentation says: Parameters:connection (DatabaseWrapper) – A Django database connection. This can be used to connect to databases other than your default database. 
So I think connection needs an object of DatabaseWrapper